# Using Torch trained VGG face

Tags: machine-learning, face-recognition, torch, vgg-net

Is there any way I can pass existing images in my system through a trained VGG with torch? I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and unfortunately do not have a GPU. I have searched quite extensively but all the ones I have found require a GPU. Are there other ways to use VGG without torch? I'm open to suggestions but the method should not require a GPU.

Answer (score 0):

While running the network using a GPU will make things a lot faster, you can run the network in CPU mode only.

Once you load the model, pretrained on a GPU you can simple convert it to CPU as follow:

```
model = model:float()
```

You can easily load an image from your computer with the help of the [image](https://github.com/torch/image) library and then do a forward pass

`local img = image.load(imagefile,3,'byte')
 local output = model:forward(img)`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Which VGG model are you talking about and where can I find it?

Comment: @Sibi You can find here a list of the available pretrained networks: https://github.com/torch/torch7/wiki/ModelZoo (they are caffe models), and you can load them as a torch model using loadcaffe module as described in the link from above.